# How can I make my application I filter a custom inherited angular default filter it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to repackage the currency filter，someone knows filter inherited way?

If anyone knows the best solution, please tell me, I would be appreciate it!!!!

Comment: You want to create a filter that extends the currency filter? Your best bet might be to just copy it and have your own. You can sometimes override built in directive behavior, just depends on what you want to do. Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: yes,I want to creat a filter extends the currency filter

Answer (score 0):

You can list more than one filter in your expression.

First, use the currency filter, then follow up in the same expression with your own custom filter.

For example:

```
<p>{{model.property | currency: '€' | customfilter}}</p>
```

customfilter here is the filter you defined. the value of model.property will first be processed by the standard Angular currency filter, then the result will in turn be processed by your customfilter. The final result is displayed.